# Call a controller method in AJAX from an User Control view in areas folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax

I had a asp.net project, with a Area folder for the asp.net mvc 2 code.
When I created the area, it creted a "View" and a "Controller" folder.

My View is a partial view, so an .ascx. 
From this view, I want to call a controller method in Ajax.

This is my code of my view :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#<%=btnSearch.ClientID %>").click(function() {
    var text = $("#<%=tbSearchBox.ClientID %>").val;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Areas/Settings/User/SearchUser',
        success: function(msg) {
            alert("toto");
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Areas is the area's folder name, Settings, the name of the folder which contains the Controller and the View folder, User is a controller of the folder Controller (UserController) and SearchUser is the method that I want to call.

At this moment, this method has just :

```
/// <summary>
/// Évènement déclenché lors de la recherche d'un utilisateur.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">Le texte à chercher.</param>
/// <returns>OK</returns>
public string SearchUser(string text)
{
    return "OK";
}
```

I get on chrome :

```
GET http://localhost/Areas/Settings/User/SearchUser 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I do ?

Comment: Can you show your routing setup?

Comment: @Andrei
Here my default routing setup :
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
  {
   context.MapRoute(
    "Settings_default",
    "Settings/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace hard-coded url by Url.Action(..) method:

```
..
url: '<%= Url.Action(..) %>',
..
```

Comment: I would try, but I have this error : A ViewUserControl can be used only in pages that derive from ViewPage or ViewPage<TViewItem>.
Because i'm in a userControl with this directive : <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MdbProcurement.Adoria.Web.Areas.Settings.Models.UserTreeViewModel>" %> ? Thanks for help !